# Similar fields while merging PDFs using iText

Tags: java, pdf, merge, itext

I seem to have a weird problem when doing a merge using iText on 2 PDF documents/forms that have similar editable fields. On merging the output document contains the 2 original documents as page 1 & page 2 . However , and here's the weird part, the numeric input fields on the first page (from document 1) have values that are a sum of the values of the 2 forms/documents.

I'm really not sure what's going on here. I have iText version 2.1.7 and it uses the `copyAcroForm()` method to copy the forms. Not sure if that is the problem, but any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: iText 2.1.7 was declared End-of-Life many years ago. It is no longer supported and [can not be used in a commercial context](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5). The current version is iText 7 and merging forms is much easier now. You have to make a decision though: if two different forms have fields with the same name, you might have to rename them if the fields with the same name have a different meaning (and different content).

Comment: Other tip: Use PdfSmartCopy to reduce the file size. But the problem you are describing seems not possible: To summate two field content is only possible using javascript. If you merge two documents which contain the same fields then those fields should become "autofill" fields meaning they contain the same value (two widgets, one value). So whatever field you change - all other "autofill" fields are changed, too...